# How to Present an (Essentially) The Same Proof, in a Different, Earlier Working Paper, in a Present Paper?

Tags: peer-review, paper-submission, self-plagiarism

I was requested to provide a simple proof for a side assertion made in one of my submissions. Regarding feasibility, it can be done; but the simplest proof that I came up with is already present in another 
earlier submission under review, and hence, to avoid "self-repetition", I did not give the simplest possible proof in the present one. The situation could be easier if I have the older one time-labeled.

What is a wise way out given the situation? Thanks.

Comment: Did you publish a preprint online (arxiv,...)? You could refer to the preprint in the newer submission and, if the older submission got accepted, edit your newer submission with an updated reference. In any case, you should ask the editor.

Answer (score 2):

Presumably you cited the earlier work. If so, I don't really understand the concern. But, if the editor/reviewer/conference would accept it, you could offer to show them the proof separately from your new paper. This would permit them to verify the result if they think it necessary.

But you were correct in not including the result in the new paper. But that also assumes that the earlier paper will actually be published. And it is possible that it won't be.

However, there is an alternative, but it would also require some editor assistance. For purpose of review, you could include the proof but note that it would need to be replaced by a citation if the earlier paper gets accepted. The final, published, version would be a bit different from what was reviewed, but that is normally the case anyway. The easy way to include the proof would be in an appendix.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the words. I have some derived query please. Would it be acceptable (with respect to the "common sense" of the society) to include the proof, perhaps an essential sketch version of it, in a footnote and indicates that the proof is already contained in another manuscript?

Comment: That is up to the editor. But you need to guard against double publication as you note. But the editor/reviewer may well be able to deal with the temporal issues of another paper under review.